# How to Append Content to Current Page (Active Tab) DOM Using Chrome Extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to add some content to active document(Active tab) by Chrome extension. Here is what I have:

popup.html

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" id="clear" type="submit"></button>
```

popup.js

```
$('#clear').on('click', function () {
    $('tr').eq(0).append("Some Test");
});
```

and manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Adder",
  "description": "Adding Content",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background" : {
  "scripts" : ["jquery.min.js","popup.js"],
  "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
   "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "popup.js"],
   "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

> Update

```
$('#clear').on('click', function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 
    'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"' });
     alert("test");
});
```

Comment: are you sure $ is a function (jQuery is included in the environment)?

Comment: Thanks TKol I updated the code and also post by adding the `"jquery.min.js` but the same thing happening. not able to add the content there

Comment: [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) ?

Comment: sorry Gabriel, can you please let me know more about this?

Comment: To inject code in the active tab from a content script you can use :
 `chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"' });`
sample code from the [doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi)

Comment: I tried your comment as I updated the code but still nothing happening!

Comment: `popup.js` is background or content script ? The `executeScript` is only for background, I think. Are you sure the `on click` is working ?